# invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getAction()' on a null object referenceid.view.KeyEvnt.getAction()

Tags: android, android-studio, keyevent

I have this code:

```
public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    });
```

And is returning this error

> at
>   widget.ClearableEditText$1.onEditorAction(ClearableEditText.java:34)

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `actionID` instead of `action_event`. Hope it will be solved. Sample code below:-

```
your_edittextfield.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override public boolean onEditorAction(TextView edt, int actionId, KeyEvent key) {
        boolean handled=false;
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //Do your task here
            handled=true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help, pleasure is all mine. :)